# Pyinstaller - ImportError: No module named mtrand in Linux

Tags: python, numpy, executable, pyinstaller

I am trying to build an executable using pyinstaller and ran in to trouble with certain modules not being/getting imported. Here is the smallest piece of code for which gives various errors. I was able to fix first few errors but am stuck on the current one.

```
import numpy as np
def test_module():
    print "Test Starts"
    a=np.array([(1,4),(2,6),(3,9),(4,1)])
    print np.size(a)
    print np.shape(a)
    print "Test Ends"

test_module()
```

With the default spec file that was generated, I was getting the error “import multiarray failed”.
By adding the numpy path in pathex under Analysis in .spec file, this error got fixed.

Now I am getting an error “ImportError: No module named mtrand”

But I have “random.mtrand.so” and “numpy.random.mtrand.so” in the dist folder.
I also tried copying the “mtrand.so” from “/numpy/ramdom/mtrand.so”
I have also checked by giving ‘numpy’ , ‘numpy.random’ or ‘numpy.random.mtrand’ in hidden imports as well.

I am still not able to fix this issue.

Comment: 1) what operating system are you compiling on?

2) what command are you using for compiling?

3) what operating system are you trying to run the executable on?

Comment: @Onedot618 The OS used for building the executable is Linux Ubuntu 14.04. I am using the command "pyinstaller mycode.spec " to create the executable. I am testing the executable in the same PC where the executable was built.